# discord.py: Lookup user by id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm new to making Discord bots using Python. I have a list of user ids and I need to be able to resolve them to Discord usernames. Running `client.get_user(my_id)` returns my Discord username with discriminator, except it doesn't work on anyone else and it doesn't work for my username 100% of the time. According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_user), I should be able to run it for any user ID but it returns None no matter what. No matter what I look up, I always get the same answer -- `client.get_user()` and it's driving me crazy. My code to run the bot is as follows

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.b ')
client.remove_command('help')
------
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Please include a more complete example of your code, an example that we could execute to encounter your problem. That would help us, help you. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running discord.py v1.5, please see [this documentation page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) on how to enable Privileged Intents for your bot.  This is a recent change that would explain why your bot cannot see any users.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly the problem. `get_user` will not work for any users that are not in any guilds with the bot. However, [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#discord.Client.fetch_user) will work for all users:

```py
await client.fetch_user(user_id)
```

Ensure that `user_id` is an integer, not a string. Also, use this sparingly as it is an API call and thus is subject to rate limits.